# How to make an existing row read only and newly added row in a table editable

Tags: knockout.js

I have a requirement where I need to add a row in to a table with default values from the      first row by clicking an "add row" button. The existing row should be read only and new row should be editable.

My HTML code is:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: TPItems()">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: beginrange"> </span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: endrange"></span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: lstpricetomu"></span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span data-bind=
            "text: offmulptomutp"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: mltusrtargprice"></span></td>
            <td><button data-bind="click: $root.removePCAttribute">
                Delete Row</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button data-bind="click: $root.addPCAttribute">Add
        Row</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My View model is:

```
function PriceCatalogTieredPricingViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    //self.thetest=ko.observable(false);

    self.defaultTPvalues = {
        itemnum: ko.observable("1127"),
        beginrange: ko.observable(""),
        endrange: ko.observable(""),
        multiuserflrprice: ko.observable(" $12.50 "),
        lstprice: ko.observable(" $999.95 "),
        lstpricetomu: ko.observable("0%"),
        mltiusrlstprice: ko.observable(" $999.95 "),
        offmulptomutp: ko.observable("50%"),
        mltusrtargprice: ko.observable(" $499.98 ")
    };

    self.TPItems = ko.observableArray(
    [
    new PCTieredPricingClass({
        itemnum: ko.observable("1127"),
        beginrange: ko.observable("1"),
        endrange: ko.observable("1"),
        multiuserflrprice: ko.observable(" $12.50 "),
        lstprice: ko.observable(" $999.95 "),
        lstpricetomu: ko.observable("0%"),
        mltiusrlstprice: ko.observable(" $999.95 "),
        offmulptomutp: ko.observable("50%"),
        mltusrtargprice: ko.observable(" $499.98 "),
        thetest: ko.observable(false)
    })]);

    self.addPCAttribute = function () {
        self.TPItems.push(new PCTieredPricingClass(self.defaultTPvalues));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new PriceCatalogTieredPricingViewModel());
});
```

Comment: Use template binding. One template for read-only and one for write.

Comment: You can have extra field as isEditable which will be true for new row.

Comment: thanks for the information. I am new to knockout Can you please tell me how to use template binding for this requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra field isEditble like this

```
self.defaultTPvalues = {
    itemnum: ko.observable("1127"),
    beginrange: ko.observable(""),
    endrange: ko.observable(""),
    multiuserflrprice: ko.observable(" $12.50 "),
    lstprice: ko.observable(" $999.95 "),
    lstpricetomu: ko.observable("0%"),
    mltiusrlstprice: ko.observable(" $999.95 "),
    offmulptomutp: ko.observable("50%"),
    mltusrtargprice: ko.observable(" $499.98 "),
    isEditble  : ko.observable(false)
};
```

And this will distinguish your newly added rows

```
self.addPCAttribute = function () {
    self.defaultTPvalues.isEditble(true)
    self.TPItems.push(new PCTieredPricingClass(self.defaultTPvalues));
}
```

EDITS

I assume you will only edit or delete the field which is editable and wont do anything with default rows. Here is conditional check

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: TPItems()">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: beginrange"> </span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: endrange"></span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: lstpricetomu"></span></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span data-bind=
        "text: offmulptomutp"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: mltusrtargprice"></span></td>
        <!-- ko if:isEditable -->
        <td><button data-bind="click: $root.removePCAttribute">Delete Row</button></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot:isEditable -->
        <td></td>
        <!-- /ko -->            
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.I am new to this Knockout Can you please tell me how to use that isEditable property in HTML table . I mean how to add extra field as isEditable. I am not getting it

Comment: Is that edits are solution for my problem?? because even the new code is not working.

Comment: Add New Row button itself is not working when I added the above code. Do I need to add anything apart from the above code??